# How to update software without replacing the files

Tags: architecture, updates, software-design

When I want to update a deployed software, I do the following:
1.make the changes in the source files
2.compile 3. Take the compiled files and place them in the old software’s place

But how to do a “patching” like update

When i only add some files without replacing the old ones, how does this work ?

Comment: depends on what language/stack/environment do you use.

Comment: @GuruStron Let say .NET Core, how to update an app with just adding an extra .dll file ?

Comment: It depends. If app is deployed as single file - then it is not possible, for example. Other than that [binary compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/categories#binary-compatibility) library should be substitutable